# .htaccess redirect https to http website not loadingup

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have my domain on Godaddy and hosting on Amazon with a SSl certificate from GoDaddy installed in the Amazon server. Hence whenever i type my domain name, its takes me in with the https prefix. Now I want to disable the SSL/https for my website. I tried the same using the below code;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But after adding the .htaccess file, mt website stopped loading up. Can you help me on this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you clear your cache before testing this?

Comment: I tested it in incognito window. Still the same